# Exposing SiteMap on IIS when using IISNode

Tags: iis, iis-10, iisnode

For a SvelteKit app hosted on Windows Server 2019 IIS v10.0.17763.1 using iisnode, I'm struggling to get the sitemap.xml file, which is in the root folder, to be publicly visible. This feels like an IIS web.config issue, but I'm not sure if the way I'm hosting via iisnode is complicating things since the root of the site is technically not visible directly hence `https....mysite.com/sitemap.xml` returns a `404 - File or directory not found` error.

See below web.config file with `SiteMap` rule.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;*.cjs" />  
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.cjs" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="node">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.cjs" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SiteMap" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="sitemap.xml" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/sitemap.xml" appendQueryString="false" />       
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="back">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="(.*)/server.cjs" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!-- security headers here -->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

server.cjs

```js
process.env.SOCKET_PATH = process.env.PORT;
delete process.env.PORT

import('./index.js')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Using iisnode is a red flag. HttpPlatformHandler gives you clear control over the requests, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ 2) If you plan to use `customHeaders` to add CORS response headers, you can also on the wrong path, as IIS CORS module is there.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information. and here are the same error message here, you can use it as a reference: [HTTP error 404 - File not found error message on a server that is running IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-404-file-not-found-error).